# Codeigniter: get all values from single column as array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Here is my query to get a single column from t

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `loc8_groups`";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql);
 print_r($query>result());
```

Its produce array result like this way.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```

But i want result as single associative array that contains all the `ids`.

Comment: why not convert it after the result is retrieved ?

Answer (score 22):

Try this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `loc8_groups`";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$array1=$query>result_array();
$arr = array_map (function($value){
    return $value['id'];
} , $array1);
 print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Only this solution. CI have only 4 functions to return results - result(), result_array(), row(), row_array(); http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html

Answer (score 20):

CodeIgniter's DB implementation doesn't support indexed result arrays, you have to choose between object or associative array.

This is done to make your queries more maintainable, as returning numeric indexes are harder to debug and maintain.

[CodeIgniter Docs - database results](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

but you can do it, i am suggesting very useful inbuilt function [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for you

`array_column()` **returns the values from a single column of the input, identified by the column_key**. Optionally, an index_key may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column of the input array.

**it will convert your codeigniter's associative array to indexed array.**

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `loc8_groups`";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$array = $query->result_array();
$arr = array_column($array,"id");
print_r($arr);
```

it will produce array as below:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1

   [1] => 2

   [2] => 3

)
```

Answer (score 3):

use mysql group_concat, to avoid foreach or using array_map,etc.

```
$sql = "SELECT group_concat(id separator ',') as id FROM `loc8_groups`";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$array1 = $query->row_array();
$arr = explode(',',$array1['id']);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Researchers, be warned: 1.) `GROUP_CONCAT()` has a maximum length of 1024. 2.) The default separator is already a comma, so this need not be specified. 3.) This technique would become unreliable if the targetted column might have values containing commas.

Comment: row_array will only result the first row

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 $result=$this->db->select('id')->get('loc8_groups')->result_array();

 $array=array_map (function($value){
                return $value['id'];
            } , $result);

 print_r($array);
```

Comment: This advice was already recommended a year earlier at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38738889/2943403

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `loc8_groups`";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

$result = array();
$index = 0;
while($row = $query->unbuffered_row('array'))
{
    $result[] = $row['id'];
    $index++;
}
```

And the result would be like this:

```
array(100) {
[0]=>
    string(1) "1"
[1]=>
    string(1) "2"
[2]=>
    string(1) "3"
...
```

Without extra conversions, and i don't see it as a limitation in codeigniter at all, any other framework that provides an extra function for this just does the same under the hood and in codeigniter you can do anything you want if you studied the framework well.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a little something like this:

```
$hold = ModelName::find('first', array('conditions' => array('register_id = ? AND table_id = ?', $this->register, $table->id)));
```

Or maybe

```
$hold = ModelName::find('all', array('conditions' => array('register_id = ? AND table_id = ?', $this->register, $table->id)));
```

Comment: Please provide the link to the CodeIgniter documentation that explains static method `find()`.